# How to update the column in one table by doing union in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I Have 2 tables and i want to do union of 2 tables and update the column in one table.

```
UPDATE table1 set field =(select table2.field from table2 where 
                    st_union(ARRAY(table1.geom,table2.geom))
```

But i am getting the follo error

```
ERROR: argument of WHERE must be type boolean, not type geometry
SQL state: 42804
Character: 111
```

How can i update the column by doing union of two geometries.

Comment: If you answer these questions: 1) What value should `table1.field` get? 2) which rows in `table1` should be updated? I'd understand the problem better.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe 1) in table1 the field column has tobe updated with the values selected from table2 field column

Comment: Right, and which row from `table2` should be picked in the subselect (I understand your query as little as PostgreSQL does)?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe the same field as in table1

Comment: No, I mean which *row* of `table2`. In other words, what is the meaning of your condition `st_union(ARRAY(table1.geom,table2.geom))`?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe i want to update table1.name with table2.name by doing union of the geometries of both table1 and table2

Comment: The thing after `WHERE` must be either `TRUE` or `FALSE`. I still don't understand what you want to do.